# Site usage details for SharePoint 2016 sites programmatically

Tags: development, powershell, 2016, site-usage, audit-log-reports

In SharePoint 2016 we can get the site usage report from

> Site Settings-> Popularity and Search Reports

But I want to get the site usage details programmatically(PowerShell/C#). I am not able to find the anything. Any leads will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think its possible using Powershell.

Please follow this link below it has information about Powershell script which use Micrsoft Graph API to get the site Usage Report.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-Office365-usage-f955ade4